# I want to convert a list of lists of tuples to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists, dictionary-comprehension

Input is

```
[('monday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), 
('tuesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), 
('wednesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00')]
```

The needed output is

```
[{'dayOfweek': 'monday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']},
 {'dayOfweek': 'tuesday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']},
  {'dayOfweek': 'wednesday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']}]
```

I am a beginner in this please help me out.

Comment: Can we assume that your input will never contains 2 items for the same day ? For example to include a lunch break ?

Comment: Yes input will not include 2 items for same day

Answer (score 0):

We will use a list comprehension:

```
list1=[('monday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), 
('tuesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), 
('wednesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00')]
```

we create a `new_list`

```
new_list=[{'dayOfweek': list1[i][0], 'time': list(list1[i][1:3])} for i in range(len(list1))]
```

**Output**

```
>>> print(new_list)

[{'dayOfweek': 'monday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']},
 {'dayOfweek': 'tuesday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']},
 {'dayOfweek': 'wednesday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginner friendly solution:

```
tuple_list = [('monday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), ('tuesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), ('wednesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00')]
dict_list = []
for t in tuple_list:
  temp_dict = {}
  temp_dict['dayOfWeek'] = t[0]
  temp_dict['time'] = [t[1], t[2]]
  dict_list.append(temp_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
print(dict_list)

[{'dayOfWeek': 'monday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']},
 {'dayOfWeek': 'tuesday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']},
 {'dayOfWeek': 'wednesday', 'time': ['09:00:00', '17:00:00']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list `l_in` and build the output list `l_out`.

Each entry is decomposed by using [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) : `day, *time =`

Here using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) a Python mechanism to easily create a list.

```py
l_in = [('monday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), ('tuesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), ('wednesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00')]
l_out = [{"dayOfWeek:": {"day": day, "time": time}} for day, *time in l_in]
```

Here using a "traditional" loop.

```py
l_in = [('monday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), ('tuesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00'), ('wednesday', '09:00:00', '17:00:00')]
l_out = []
for x in l_in:
    day, *time = x
    l_out.append({"dayOfWeek:": {"day": day, "time": time}})
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this one using list comprehension, it worked

Answer (score 0):

The concept is to iterate through all input values and breaking them down to constituent parts.

```
from __future__ import annotations

def convert(input:list[tuple])->list[dict]:
    """
    This function takes in a list of tuples and returns a list of dictionaries

    Use of annotations help you define your input types
    """
    # your output list
    output=[]
    for x in input:
        # dictionary to store each intermediate value
        dict={}
        dict['dayOfweek']=x[0]

        # iterate through the remaining tuples to get the time component
        dict['time']=[t for t in x[1:]]

        # add this dictionary record to your output list
        output.append(dict)

    print(output)
    return output
```